# How to filter non-digits from string

Tags: swift

My phone numbers are like +7 (777) 777-7777.
I need only digits and plus symbol: +77777777777 to make calls.

This returns only digits:

```
let stringArray = origString.componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet(NSCharacterSet.decimalDigitCharacterSet().invertedSet)
let newString = NSArray(array: stringArray).componentsJoinedByString("")
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One of the many ways to do that:

```
let isValidCharacter: (Character) -> Bool = {
   ($0 >= "0" && $0 <= "9") || $0 == "+"
}

let newString = String(origString.characters.filter(isValidCharacter))
```

or using a regular expression:

```
// not a +, not a number
let pattern = "[^+0-9]"

// replace anything that is not a + and not a number with an empty string
let newString = origString.replacingOccurrences(
    of: pattern,
    with: "",
    options: .regularExpression
)
```

or, if you really want to use your original solution with a character set.

```
let validCharacters = CharacterSet(charactersIn: "0123456789+")
let newString = origString
   .components(separatedBy: validCharacters.inverted)
   .joined()
```

Comment: well put @Sulthan

Comment: I suggest you read up about regular expressions, for parsing phone numbers

Answer (score 3):

In keeping with the spirit of your partial solution,

```
let origString:NSString = "+7 (777) 777-7777"
let cs = NSCharacterSet(charactersIn: "0123456789+")
let final = origString.components(separatedBy: cs.inverted).joined()
```

Comment: This is Swift, therefore `String` and `CharacterSet`.

Comment: Both are fine @Sulthan.